# Can I sync oAuth / OpenID user data from a bespoke server

Tags: oauth, openid

I am working on a server with a legacy user set and user roles. The server exposes a REST API which use a gross set of roles to authenticate with.
The owners now want to move to a new authentication scheme and OpenID Connect seems like a good fit, due to there being a requirement to identify users. Also the authentication server has to run in a cluster ( there's reasons! )

My question is, is it possible to sync the existing roles on the server to an OpenID container so that any client asking for access to those roles can be authenticated?